# Microsoft Graph ListMessages API not providing the emails

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am currently using `Microsoft Graph API v1` to retrieve the list of messages present in a user's inbox and I have all the necessary scopes listed in order to read and write messages on behalf of the user, the scopes are

- openid,
- email
- profile
- offline_access
- https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read
- https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.readwrite
- https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send
- https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
  When I make an api call to fetch all the messages from the mailFolder `INBOX` through the api [`listMessages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API, I am getting the messages, but the api in itself doesn't return some mails even though I can see them in my Inbox folder in Outlook UI.
  Are there any other settings or parameter that I need to enable in order to get all the mails?
  The receiver from whom I received the mail is in my SafeSender List and not in any Blocked List
  Any suggestions or answer would be helpful

An example code of what I am doing is as follows

```js
function getUserMessages() {
   const baseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages";
   return axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseUrl,
          headers:{
             "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
             }
          }).then((result) => result.data);
}

// Here in the messages I get, I don't see some of the mails which are 
// present in the inbox Folder
const messages = getUserMessages();
```

Comment: This is the code I wrote. I get the green channel to be able to separate the colours and then I amplify the different colours with "contrast_adjuster" to get a better threshold at the end. But I can't get a very good threshold.

Comment: You really need to show your code.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have update my question with the code which I am using

Answer (score 0):

Graph pages the returned messages. You can specify `$top` and `$skip` query parameters (in addition to `$orderBy`). It also returns `@odata.nextLink` value in JSON response that you can use to request the next page.

Comment: I am seeing the mail which I want to receive in the api on the first page of outlook inbox UI and still I am not getting that specific mail in API if I go through all the `nextLink` values

Comment: The sort order you see in Outlook has nothign to do with the order in which Graph returns the messages unless you explicitly request a particular sort order.

Comment: Do you see the same issue in OutlookSpy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you click Folder on the Graph group on the OutlookSpy ribbon and go to the messages tab?